# What kind of object is being checked against the cache when a new query arrives?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, database-internals, cache

After reading several resources, it's not clear to me what kind of object is being checked against SQL Server Plan Cache when a new query arrives.

I see 3 possible options:

1. The pure query text.
2. The parse tree (the resultant object of the parser)
3. The query plan (the resultant object of the optimizer. Below, I refer to it as a "compiled query").

Now, since the cache is actually called "The Plan Cache", it may indicate that option 3 must be the correct one.

However, it seems to me that the third option must be false. First, because the "Plan Cache" actually caches other object than just compiled plans (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx)). Secondly, as I see it, the purpose of accessing the cache is to prevent an unnecessary compilation of the arrived query. Thus, if the access to the cache is done against a *compiled query*, it requires the *compilation of the new query*, which misses the whole point.

I read one resource that supports this view, saying that the cache is being checked *before* the Query Optimizer takes place, i.e., before the generation of the query plan (taken from Professional SQL Server 2012 Internals and Troubleshooting, pg. 113, under the "Query Optimization" section):

> The current model provided by the SQL Server team works something like
>   this:
>
> Is a valid plan cached? If yes, then use the cached plan. If no plan
>   exists, then continue [and apply simplification and optimization,
>   which results in a query plan].

So it seems option 2 is the right one. However, in two other resources I found a support for option 3. This is the first one ([source](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)):

> When a query is submitted to the server, an estimated execution plan
>   is created by the optimizer. Once that plan is created, and before it
>   gets passed to the storage engine, the optimizer compares this
>   estimated plan to actual execution plans that already exist in the
>   plan cache . If an actual plan is found that matches the estimated
>   one, then the optimizer will reuse the existing plan, since it’s
>   already been used before by the query engine.

And The following text (taken from Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Bible, pages 1042 and 1044) claims the same: The query plan is checked against the cache after its generation (Note that it uses slightly different terms and it differs from the above text regarding the component that is responsible for the request to check the cache):

> After the query execution plan generates [By the query optimizer], SQL Server stores it in the
>   Plan Cache [...] and
>   informs the Query Processor that the plan is ready to be executed.
>
> [...]
>
> When the query processor needs to execute a query, it first checks to
>   see if the query can reuse an execution plan already in the Plan
>   Cache. It’s much faster to find and reuse a Query Execution Plan than
>   to generate a new plan, even though that option is not always the best
>   solution.

Is there a decisive answer for this?